# Selenium XPath Not Found Error in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have an HTML page (opening using Firefox and/or Chrome), and I am trying to find the correct XPath of the (image) Element I am trying to click on the webpage. I'm coding in C# using Selenium Automation. Here is how the element looks like when I right-click and select inspect:

(The actual website is too long so I'm subbing it with {website} and {different-website}).

EDIT: I'm sorry I forgot, but the {website} is dynamic. And {different-website} is static.

```
<a href="https://{website}">
<img border="0" alt="open now" src="https://{different-website}.gif">
</a>
```

I'm trying to click the img using my automation, but everything I try the automation fails and says "Unable to locate element". I notice that the img im trying to click is kind of nested into the above {a} element. Maybe that's why it is so difficult to select and click.
I've tried things such as:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[starts-with(@href='https://www.{website}')]")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href='https://www.{website}')]")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[(@src,'img1935.gif')]")).Click(); 

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[(@src,'img1935.gif')]/../a")).Click(); 

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[not(@href)/img/@src | //a[img]/@href")).Click(); 

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@alt='open now']/@src")).Click(); 

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@alt='open now']/@src")).Click();
```

All of these returned "Unable to locate Element" and I'm stuck on what else I should do or try. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of your XPaths won't find what you are looking for. Have you tried something simple like

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/img[@alt='open now']")).Click();
```

If this doesn't work, you need to provide more info or a link to the page.

Comment: This doesn't work also I can't actually give out the website link because its classified (hence the dynamic behavior) but the only thing I can really see when I inspect the webpage is that what I'm trying to click is nested inside of a paragraph. Thanks for trying to help also

Comment: Try this... go to the page you are using and type `$x("//a/img[@alt='open now']")` in the dev console... what does it return?

Comment: Hmm... I have 3 of them on the page after typing that in. I have 3 of the same images with that exact XPath. Maybe that's why Selenium couldn't locate it. But since I have 3, shouldn't it have been able to find one of those?

Comment: The first one (and others?) may not be visible? I guess it depends on the error message you are getting when it fails.

Comment: They may not be, I don't know why they wouldn't bet though. But the error I always get is: OpenQA.Selenium.No.Such.ElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a/img[@alt='open now']"} The method changes to whatever I type in to attempt, but the error stays the same.

Comment: Maybe it's a timing issue... are you waiting for the page to finish loading? You might try adding a breakpoint right before this line, let the page load, and then proceed. If it works, it's likely a timing issue... just wait for some element to load on that section of the page and then do your search.

Comment: I'm waiting for 10 seconds prior to trying to click the element. But I will wait for longer to see if that'e the problem and will let you know the results.

Comment: Just tried it with 30 and 45 seconds and still the same result Unable to locate element

Comment: Does the `$x()` command above find them on the page when Selenium can't?

Comment: Yes, they are found using that command. But not found using Selenium. Its weird. I know how to write XPaths because I've written like near a hundred of them for my project, but this one is just weird and Selenium is not cooperating with me.

Comment: I figured it out, the Xpath was in a different tab, so I had to switch drivers to the new tab in order to find it. Thanks so much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `//a[@href="https://{website}"]/img[1]`

- All `a` elements (where href = "http://{website}")
- Then select the first `img` child element of those elements

You can [test it here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) - that website will also give suggestions.

I find [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) really useful when trying to work out `XPath`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this will not work with a dynamic {website}, I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic urls the you should avoid using fixed path in the selector.You can use something like:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'part_of_href_value')]
```

If the link is translated for different websites you can use something like:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'part_of_href_value1') or contains(@href, 'part_of_href_value2') or contains(@href, 'part_of_href_value3')]
```

You can use any part of the href. You can adapt the above selectors for images also, replace `a` with `img` and `@href` with `@src`

Example:
I have 2 links with href's:
`href=https://www.example1.com/blabla/page 

href=http://www.second-example.org/bla/page-s`

To select both links, i use example word since is common:
    `//a[contains(@href, 'example')]`

To select both links by different parts/words:
    `//a[contains(@href, 'blabla/page') or contains(@href, 'bla/page')]`

Comment: I've tried that also, it doesn't locate the element by using contains. Also whenever I enter the website for it to contain such as:" //a[contains(@href,'https://{website}')]", the "//" makes the whole website link turn blue. I don't know if its not finding the element because of the "//". I'm also assuming when using contains, I have to start from the "https://" but not have to enter the whole website address. Is that correct?

Comment: No.When you are using contains you can start from from anywhere and copy the part that you need.

Comment: I've tried without using the "https://" also and I had no luck with it being able to locate the element. Such as: //a[contains(@href,'https://www.google.com/search/help')]" gave me no luck. Also, I tried it like this:  //a[contains(@href,'https://search/help')]" which gave me no luck also

Comment: Make sure the links are not in any iframe, because you will ned to find that iframe and to switch to it. Also you can try to use a wait if needed.

Comment: No, they aren't in any iframe tags. Also I'm calling Thread.Sleep for 10 seconds to make sure everything on the page is visible.

Comment: You need to try these selectors in the browser first to make sure that they are ok or if you have some programming issue.Also keep in mind that when using /@src it will return the value of the src and you might not be able to click on it.

Comment: Yes, they are working separately in the browsers. And yes, I understand, I have many other XPaths working in my code, its just this one is completely different than the rest. There's no attributes in this html code which is making it extremely difficult to pinpoint and select and click the XPath of this element. Also thank you so much for your time trying to help me